# Securing a web server with local MySQL database

Tags: mysql, security, amazon-web-services, ssh, webserver

I am creating a web service for a small company which will use client authentication and possibly https for a RESTful service. I am asking a very simple question that I hope is not too broad, but I am very new and naive to internet security. What precautions must I take to ensure my data is secure?

To describe my service a bit, users have an account where they place presumably insensitive information and retrieve it from a database using a homemade authentication token I create on successful login with a salted password. I am using an amazon instance where MySQL is local and access is granted remotely to me so I can access it directly from my home. I am using a few php scripts to do my work requesting and adding data and am attempting to protect against injection. I am storing my MySQL credentials in a separate file from the php scripts. I can only ssh into my server with a pem file that I believe is safe.

My biggest fear is that someone will come and delete all of my data. What other precautions must I take? Thanks

Comment: you should not have your mysql daemon available from the public internet, without an firewall to block all requests beside your own (allow your ip if it needs to be, and forbid all others)

Comment: Make sure you don't have any `username@%` grants in your MySQL permissions. Only allow `username@localhost` and `username@yourIP`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Securing a simple Linux server that holds a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641319/securing-a-simple-linux-server-that-holds-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Amazon EC2 then you should make use of their security groups to lock down your MySQL server and ensure that no external access to it is possible.

Application servers have an internal non-routing 10.x type IP that should be used for access control, and any external IPs, like your home network, should be specifically whitelisted if VPN access or SSH tunnelling is not practical, as those two are far easier to secure.

Be **absolutely** sure that no credentials, configuration files, or keys are stored anywhere in your web root. That is, should you accidentally misconfigure your application server in the worst possible way, with directory indexes turned on and everything, it's not possible to snag anything critical.

You might also want to specifically exclude the downloading of `*.inc` in case you make a mistake. The idea here is to set up a number of safeguards you'd have to break before things go horribly awry. A single-mistake failure situation is always the result of bad planning.

Above all else, be **extremely** vigilant about [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) as no amount of firewall security on your MySQL server will help you when someone can drive a truck through a mistake in your code and have free reign on the server. It's recommended to thoroughly audit any SQL interfacing code you've written before going live with it.

Be sure to have a proper deployment procedure that uses a version control system. If you ever have an intrusion it's very easy to roll back to a known-good version of the code if you have one. The 1990s style "throw files at server with FTP" deployment approach is hazardous at the best of times and fatal to your business when it goes wrong. Use version control or you're living on borrowed time.

Comment: Thanks for you advice? When you say don't store credentials in my web root, where should I store them instead so I can include them in php? For injection, I am using intval() or mysqli_real_escape_string() for all of my GET or POST variables, is this sufficient? Thanks again

Comment: Store your credentials outside of that, so if you have `mysite/public` then you'd use `mysite/includes` as an example. Also, avoid using `intval`, that's not a general purpose solution. Parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) is the best way to add user data to your query without creating security problems.

Comment: So, 1)Use security groups to limit access to my server from everyone but me, 2)Store database credentials outside of the web root, 3)Use proper SQL escaping, 4)Use a version control system to roll back in case of the worst. It probably isn't a bad idea to get rid of the 'user'@'%' mysql user either

Comment: You should be using random strings for anything critical. Usually I set the MySQL administrator password to be 30 random characters and save that somewhere secure. Your application will never have to type that password in, so make it robust. Something like `letmein` is not sufficient.